# Correct way to convert datetime timezone for display

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

We are developing a website and currently, the timezone of the website and database is in German time zone (European standard time zone). But the application is being accessed from the US also. There is a screen in the application which contains a **DateTime** field called **ValidFrom** and the time we are storing is **UTC** time. currently, users are not selecting the time so we are using .NET built-in **DateTime.UTCNow** to store DateTime value in the database. But the problem is while displaying, we need to display it according to User timezone. So after googling for many hours, we found two solutions one using **moment** and another approach is using **DateTime.SpecifyKind**. We tried using **moment.js** but it converted the date time to local time once again. So we ended up using **DateTime.SpecifyKind** as below.

```
[DataMember]
private DateTime _validFrom;
public DateTime ValidFrom
{
    get { return _validFrom; }
    set { _validFrom = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
}
```

And now the values are displayed according to timezone. But my doubt is, is it the correct approach to handle timezone display or any other better solution exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `DateTimeOffset` instead, something like:

```
var utc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Your Specific Time Zone Id");
var zonedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, tz);
```

Save the UTC and user's time zone in the database, and convert UTC to specific time zone any time you want to show it to your users. I also suggest you take a look at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) if you want to do anything serious with date and time. The built-in DateTime in .Net is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension method for this:

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromUTC(this DateTime date, TimeZoneInfo destZone)
{
    var utcZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, utcZone, destZone);
}
```

However, if you plan to use something like this you need to be aware of daylight saving time. The result may be off if the conversion crosses a DST change in either timezone. So it isn't really suitable if you need absolute precision, which depends on the website, e.g.: is it a blog or a stock trading app?

Comment: absolute precision is needed. including milliseconds.